# What does Martin Waldseemüller mean by "asie partis" in his map Carta Marina?

Tags: syntax, declension, morphology, word-usage, renaissance-latin

This [webpage from Spanish BBC](https://www.bbc.com/mundo/noticias-47915630) talks about the second main map by Martin Waldseemüller, the first mapper to name the continent America, called Carta Marina. There, we see the southern portion of America being called Terra Nova, with the east coast "Brasilia or lands of the parrots", and the northern portion "Terra de Cuba · Asie partis", likely after the island of Cuba encountered by Colombo in his first trip to the new world.
[image]

The Spanish BBC translates Asie partis as "part of Asia". Most people, even without knowledge of Latin declension, would imagine that is what it means, and perhaps Asie is simply Asiæ, indeed, æ has /e/ or /ε/ sound. But how does 'partis' make any sense?

Partis can be many things:

1. Conjugation of "partio", "you are splitting".
2. Dative or vocative past participle of pario, "(of) that was equaled".
3. Genetive singular of pars, (of the part)

It is clear that neither 1 or 2 make any sense in this context, and the only possible answer is 3, but should it not be Asie pars instead of Asie partis? I imagine Asie partis would mean of the part of Asia, which does not make sense in this context, as it follows a "·", which implies it is a title; and even if it were not, saying "Land of Cuba of a part of Asia" makes no sense either.

So what is meant here?

Comment: *Partis* is also an alternative form of the accusative plural, but it doesn't seem to lead to anything more sensible unless we are to understand a suitable word left out.

Comment: Do you have access to a zoomable picture of the entire map? Perhaps we can glean some hints by other texts in this map.

Comment: @d_e You would not really find much, as the section I presented gives all the information relative to that section, but since you asked, here it is https://www.faena.com/sites/default/files/inline-images/cart1090222.jpg . It makes me imagine that Waldseemuller was not so good at Latin, but that is hard to believe.

Comment: If we allow a bit of mixing between classic latin and post-medieval latin we could say that "partis" (gen. sing.) relates to "de cuba" (intended as Cubae) in terms of adposition, so that the translation Land of Cuba, part of Asia makes a bit more sense. I have nothing to support this though.

Comment: I wonder if *Asiae* here is equal to *Asianae*, so meaning something like "The Land of Cuba of the Asian part" (i.e. land of a part of Asia).

Comment: Both Davide and cmw bring up good points. It is fine that it is written de Cuba instead of Cuba, as perhaps the cartographist did not feel it appropriate to declinate a new word that is foreign; that aside, it is strange if "Cuba, part of Asia" is meant, as "Asia" is written before partis and closer to "Cuba", which renders it "Land of Cuba, of part of Asia". And even if it does mean "Land of Cuba, of part of Asia", it is still strange, as it would imply that there is a part of Cuba that is not in Asia.
Continues

Comment: For cmw, it is true Asie could be genitive female of asius (Asian), but then we would have "Land of Cuba, of Asian part". Possible, though still weird.

Comment: It's most definitely *asiae*, of that there is no doubt. It does still sound weird to me, though, as if something else is missing. The Asian part *of what* (for example)?

Comment: By the way, to ping a user, you'll have to add the @ sign in front of their name, like @Davide, which means Davide is now pinged, and will now see that you replied to his comment.